# ERROR AL EXPORTAR BASE DE DATOS(TABLAS) DE PHPMYADMIN

Tags: html, mysql, phpmyadmin

he estado teniendo un problema de exportacion de tabla en phpmyadmin, estoy trabajando en una web donde utilizo HTML,CSS y JS conectado con una base de datos MySQL en php, Todo iba con normalidad, pero en el momento que ya me tocaba publicar la pagina en una web me percate que al darle exportar a mi tabla, me aparece como Error de red sin motivo, ya que he validado mi conexión, puesto que le vuelvo a dar en reanudar la descarga(Adjunto print)[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y posterior a reanudar la misma, automáticamente dicho archivo .sql se transforma en un index.html(adjunto print)[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta el momento no he podido encontrar una solución, ya que dicha tabla me la exporta en formato HTML, si me pudieran compartir una solución se los agradecería.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ese [error de red](https://www.google.com/search?q=chrome+download+file+network+error) no es un problema de PHPMyadmin, es que un tercero está bloqueando la descarga. Primero intenta -temporalmente- deshabilitar antivirus, firewall, defender, u otro software de seguridad que tengas en ese equipo y reintenta el proceso. Si funciona, entonces has las excepciones correspondientes en el software de seguridad.

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, intente lo que me mencionas, he desactivado cualquier tipo de firewall, defender, etc, pero aun teniendo todo desactivado, sigue apareciendo el problema de error en red y descargándomelo posteriormente en HTML, que otra cosa pudiese ser ?

Comment: https://ibb.co/F3MR9Mp (Img de todo desactivado)

Comment: Ok, olvida lo que dije, parece que si es un problema reciente con últimas versiones de phpmyadmin y PHP 8.1. [Más información](https://www.google.com/search?q=network+error+phpmyadmin&tbs=qdr:m&sa=X&biw=1600&bih=789&dpr=1) al respecto.

Comment: Muchas gracias, en ese link pude encontrar la solución que era referente a la versión del PHP, te agradezco mucho.